# Python Program not working subprocess.run command. i need run powershell with parameters

Tags: python, windows, powershell

Help people find the error. I need a simple program to turn the monitor on and off according to a schedule. I chose the option of writing a program in Python. But the program refuses to call powershell, some problems with the parameters. I'm new to this. Please tell me.
this is code i use. (something is wrong in lines 31 and 35) I expect the program to work on windows 10

```
# импортируем необходимые модули\
import os
import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# устанавливаем некоторые константы, используемые в программе
FILENAME = "monitor_schedule.txt"  # имя файла, в который сохраняется расписание

# получаем путь к рабочей папке
current_directory = os.getcwd()

# определяем функцию, которая сохраняет расписание в файл
def save_schedule(start_time, end_time):
    with open(os.path.join(current_directory, FILENAME), "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{start_time},{end_time}")

# определяем функцию, которая загружает расписание из файла
def load_schedule():
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(current_directory, FILENAME), "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
            start_time, end_time = data.strip().split(",")
            return start_time, end_time
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None, None
# функция использующая powershell для включения
def turn_monitor_on():
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,-1)"])

#  функция использующая powershell для включения
def turn_monitor_off():
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)"])

# определяем функцию, которая проверяет расписание и включает/выключает монитор при необходимости
def check_schedule():
    start_time, end_time = load_schedule()
    if start_time and end_time:
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M")
        if now == start_time:
            print ('monitor must on')
            turn_monitor_on()
        elif now == end_time:
            turn_monitor_off()
            print('monitor must of')
    root.after(30000, check_schedule)
# Проверка на случайное пробуждение от мышки, выключает монитор через каждые 3 минуты
def check_schedule2():
    start_time, end_time = load_schedule()
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    print  ('Shedule2 run')
    if start_time <= now <= end_time:
            print ('monitor on')
    else:
            #turn_monitor_off()
            print ('monitor go off')
    root.after(180000,check_schedule2)

# определяем функцию, которая сохраняет расписание, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Save"
def save_button_click(start_entry, end_entry):
    start_time = start_entry.get()
    end_time = end_entry.get()

    # проверяем, что введенные значения соответствуют формату времени HH:MM
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M")
        datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, "%H:%M")
    except ValueError:
        status_label.config(text="Ошибка: время должно быть в формате HH:MM")
        return

    # приводим введенное время в нужный формат
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M").strftime("%H:%M")
    end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, "%H:%M").strftime("%H:%M")

    save_schedule(start_time, end_time)
    status_label.config(text="расписание сохранено")

# создаем главное окно программы
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Включение/Выключение Монитора")

# создаем интерфейс программы с помощью библиотеки Tkinter
start_label = tk.Label(root, text="Вкл монитора:(H:M)")
start_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

start_entry = tk.Entry(root,width = 5)
start_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

end_label = tk.Label(root, text="Выкл монитора:(H:M)")
end_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

end_entry = tk.Entry(root,width = 5)
end_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Сохранить", command=lambda: save_button_click(start_entry, end_entry))
save_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

status_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
status_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

# загружаем расписание из файла и заполняем поля ввода
start_time, end_time = load_schedule()
if start_time and end_time:
    start_entry.insert(0, start_time)
    end_entry.insert(0, end_time)

# Start the scheduler
check_schedule()
check_schedule2()
root.mainloop()
```

when I start the program I get this error when I try to start the process in powershell
Add-Type : c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(8) :  ⨯
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(7) :     {
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(8) : >>>     [DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes
monitor must of
sage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(9) :
ப:1 :2

- (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except 
  ion
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
  ```

Add-Type : c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(8) : ⨬ ⮪ "^"   ,
䥩
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(7) :     {
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(8) : >>>     [DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes
sage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\c1ilykep.0.cs(9) :
ப:1 :2

- (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except 
  ion
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
  ```

Add-Type :  㤠  ⨯. 㦥 訡 樨.
ப:1 :2

- (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
  ```

Add-Type : c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\rbe315b0.0.cs(8) :  ⨯
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\rbe315b0.0.cs(7) :     {
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\rbe315b0.0.cs(8) : >>>     [DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes
monitor must of
sage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
c:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Temp\rbe315b0.0.cs(9) :
ப:1 :2

- (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]^public static extern int SendMes ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except 
  ion
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
  ```

Comment: Please check out [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: That's a lot of code for others to sift through. One obvious problem is that the `^` char. shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, removed the character and the Powershell shell started. The monitor turned off, but for some reason the program hangs on the shell, it does not close after working out. And it turns out that the program code is not executed further. If I complete this process in the dispatcher, then the program continues to be executed.
I apologize if I wrote a lot, this is my first time on this resource. I haven’t had time to get used to it yet. It makes it a little difficult that my level of English is still low.